# Flexbox layout font breaking out of container with fittext

Tags: css, flexbox, fittextjs

I have a layout built using flexbox that takes up 100% of the viewport and then splits the screen into 4 25% height rows..

http://jsfiddle.net/g010vc2k/25/

```js
$(".row_content").fitText(.4);
```

```css
#holder{
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.button{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  clear:both;
}

.row_1{
  background:wheat;
  height:25%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
}


.row_2{
  background:teal;
  display:flex;
  height:25%;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
}
  
.row_3{
  background:yellow;
  display:flex;
  height:25%;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.row_4{
  background:gray;
  display:flex;
  height:25%;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.row_content{
  font-size:60px;
  display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FitText.js/1.2.0/jquery.fittext.js"></script>


<div id="holder">
    <div class="row_1">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  1 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
    <div class="row_2">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  2 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
    <div class="row_3">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  3 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
    <div class="row_4">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  4 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am running into a couple of problems, firstly I can't get the button to sit underneath the content in each row.  I think the display:flex might be causing me problems.

Secondly, the text is breaking out of the containers.  I though fittext would resolve this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. have you tried `flex-flow: column;`?
2. use `vw` unit in your font-size.

Answer (score 1):

- `display:flex` always align its child elements next to each other so `row` as default. Add `flex-direction:column;` to your row-elements and the buttons will place themselves below the text.
- Maybe you can add a solution without using javascript. Reduce the font-size for smaller viewports with media-queries. CSS-only is always a better option performancewise.

Further information for flexbox and media-queries:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column;` to all the rows for the vertical stacking of text and buttons, and add `margin: 0` for the `p` tags inside to prevent overlapping caused by too much spacing:

(Note: Open the snippet in full page view, otherwise the text is too large)

```js
$(".row_content").fitText(.4);
```

```css
#holder {
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
}

.row_1 {
  background: wheat;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row_2 {
  background: teal;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row_3 {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row_4 {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row_content {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.row_content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FitText.js/1.2.0/jquery.fittext.js"></script>


<div id="holder">
  <div class="row_1">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  1 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row_2">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  2 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row_3">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  3 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row_4">
    <span class="row_content">
      <p>
        Row  4 Content
      </p>
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      <button>
          Click Me
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the text is not fitting in like fittext is meant to.  Perhaps fittext has issues with flexbox